# Datagrid click only displaying messagebox on specific column name

Tags: c#, winforms

Currently a MessageBox appears each time I click on any cell on my datagrid.

Is there a way to have it display a message box when a cell in a specific column is clicked?

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Alert");
}
```

Comment: Didn't you already ask this question early today?

Comment: Yes but I couldn't work with the solution I had - so I decided to start from scratch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (e.ColumnIndex != theIndex) { return; }
```

So, in other words, if it's not the column you want get out.

---

You can't compare a `string` to an `int` value like that, do this:

```
if (e.ColumnIndex == 1) { ... }
```

Further, it's `==` not `=`. The `=` operator is an *assignment* operator.

Comment: What if I wanted to specify a particular column?

Comment: @methuselah, that is a particular column. Please be more specific and I'll provide guidance.

Comment: i.e. if I only wanted a messagebox to appear for all cells in the "DriverNo" column

Comment: @methuselah, are you implying you don't know the index of that column? Not that it's a big deal; but I'm still not fully understanding the issue with the current solution.

Comment: I've tried the following: `if (e.ColumnIndex = "1") 
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Hello");
            }` but I get a string to int error

Comment: @methuselah, see my edit. It should make it clear why that doesn't work.